# AMD Athlon II x2 270 performance

Tags: 12.04, drivers, performance, cpu

I want to buy a new PC. I want to know how does this CPU works fine on Ubuntu.

It's an AMD Athlon II x2 270.

I'm not asking for a review. I just want to know if it works fine on Ubuntu, because I've had some problems with other processors (drivers, mainly).

If it doesn't, maybe you could recommend me another (better) processor a bit cheaper.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! you can note that your question is *a little* off-topic. It have been already discussed [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1186/62483). Anyway, it could be answered, while it fit with some *requirements* mentioned there. By now your question is **too open**, because you didn't mentioned the version of Ubuntu in the **content**, *not only tag*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this processor is supported:

look at this: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Hardware-HOWTO/cpu.html#AEN417